# cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine reloads app when going back from subpage

Tags: cordova, wkwebview

Im using the plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine with my phonegap.build app.

And when I load a subpage and then swipe back to the start page, then the start page freezes for about 4 sec before I can scroll it again. And I realised that it is reloading the start page every time I go back from a subpage. Is this the expected way it should work?

1. How to prevent it from reload the startpage? Why doesn´t it work like in Safari? Since Safari is using the wkwebview! When you load a subpage and then go back Safari remembers the position off the previus page, why is this not doing that?
2. When I open a subpage it is opened in a new view on top of my start page. And I wonder if it is possible to open it in the same view as the startpage? So all pages is loaded in just one view?

Any input appreciated thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Ionic5/Angular9/CordovaAndroid8. Whenever my app resumes from the background, the webview reloads. I am still troubleshooting. Did you have any luck with this?